# Continuar un look tras un KeyError, imprimir el error y continuar el loop hasta el final de la lista

Tags: python-3.x, excel

Tengo el siguiente problema, no logro entenderlo y no no tengo instrucción formal en programación.

Desde una planilla leo en loop una lista de links las cuales las requiero por método get y busco en el JSON, un parámetro el cual imprimo a un nuevo libro.
El tema es que cuando el link no muestra en el JSON el estado se detiene todo el Scrip y  no logro hacer se salte el error, registre que está erroneo el folio y continue con las siguientes.
Hasta ahora intenté lo que sigue y si bien ya no me myestra el Keyerror y me muestra el mensaje, aún así el script se detiene y sólo guarda hasta los que llevaba en ese momento.

Intenté con algunas expresiones como except, pass, continue etc, pero no logro que resulte.

Gracias!

````
import requests as requests
import json
import xlsxwriter
import xlrd
import openpyxl
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_rowcol_to_cell as to_cell
import time

start_time = time.time()
df = pd.read_excel('Book.xlsx')

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Book_check.xlsx')  
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()                  

try:

lista_links = df['Columna_a'].to_list()


for i in range(0, len(links)):
        link = requests.get(lista[i])
        json_web = json.loads(link.text)

        estado_1 = json_web['body']['estado']
      
        print(estado_1)

        worksheet.write(to_cell(i+1, 0), estado_1)
       

except KeyError: 
    print('Folio Erroneo')
    pass

    time.sleep(5)

    workbook.close()```
````

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que poner el `try` dentro del bucle.

```
import requests as requests
import json
import xlsxwriter
import xlrd
import openpyxl
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_rowcol_to_cell as to_cell
import time

start_time = time.time()
df = pd.read_excel('Book.xlsx')

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Book_check.xlsx')  
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()                  

lista_links = df['Columna_a'].to_list()

for i in range(0, len(links)):
        try:
                link = requests.get(lista[i])
                json_web = json.loads(link.text)

                estado_1 = json_web['body']['estado']
      
                print(estado_1)

                worksheet.write(to_cell(i+1, 0), estado_1)
       

         except KeyError: 
                print('Folio Erroneo')

                time.sleep(5)

workbook.close()
```

Comment: Te lo agradezco enormemente. no lograba ver algo tan obvio, Muchas gracias!!